# Checking for errors from Scanner?

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

So I decided to make a program that makes Orc objects that each have a name.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){

            System.out.println("Input the name of your Orc here:");

            String name = input.nextLine(); //THIS is where the inputed name is registerd.

            Orcmaker Orc = new Orcmaker(name);

            System.out.println(Orc);

            input.close();
        }

        System.out.println("Fire");

        //Find a way to run validation code while not obstructing the for loop to make multiple orc objects.

    }
}
```

So I made that for loop to go through the code so that I can make a name for each orc until eventually I make 10 orcs. The problem is that I'm having issues now injecting input validation that won't make certain lines of code go blank because the loop swallowing up vital code.

Also I just don't know how to make it so that my if statement can see a number or special character to invalidate. Because these are NAMES I only want a String.

Just for completeness' sake here is my constructor. This is the only other class in this mini-project I have made myself.

```
public class Orcmaker {

private String name;
private int age;
private String weapon;

public Orcmaker(String OrcName){
    this.name = OrcName;
}

@Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(name);
  }

}
```

Comment: `String.valueOf` is entirely redundant here; just do `return name`. Also, you shouldn't capitalize normal variable names, only class names (and other type names).

Comment: Also, you're calling `input.close()` in the loop. You should call it outside of the loop. And I really don't know what you mean by "make certain lines of code go blank." But the code in your `for` loop should be indented; otherwise, it's hard to follow.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "loop swallowing up vital code".  I think you might want to add an inner `while` loop that has `input.nextLine()`, and break out of the loop if the input is valid, but if not, display an error message and loop back.

Comment: For validating that there are no numbers or special characters, use a regular expression (aka regex).  You can Google "Java tutorial regular expression" for more information.

Comment: You can use a regex for name validation and match with you input , If it will not match then display the error message on console.